# Splitting ZipArchiveEntry content while sending

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I got problem with splitting content of ZipArchiveEntry while sending it to other service.
Context: i have service with zip creating function. I got some data from third party service, generated csv file based on this data and put it into zip archive. After that, i got memorystream (which is parent for zip), read it till the end, got all contents from there, send it to another service and clean mother-stream. In my case this is necessary because there is huge possibility that data from third party services will be huge, so i need to save opportunity for chunk sending. After closing zip with using, i send eocd bytes.
But when i'm trying to recreate zip archive from those bytes, i got an exception that number of entries in CD doesn't corresponding with the actual number.

And here is my question. Is it possible to split ZipArchiveEntry content while sending it or processing it? Sole purpose of this action is reduce memory consuming.
I wrote sample. There is no sending or other stuff. It is just converting those bytes to Base64 there and back.

```cs
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

internal class Program
{
    public static readonly List<byte> Bytes = new List<byte>();
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry("entry.csv");
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(entry.Open(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    var csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";"
                    };
                    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, csvConfiguration))
                    {
                        Write(memoryStream, writer, csv);
                    }
                }
            }
            Bytes.AddRange(Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer().AsSpan(0, (int)memoryStream.Length)))); // adding eocd
        }

        var bytes = Bytes.ToArray();
        
        using var mStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        var arch = new ZipArchive(mStream); // successfully creating zipArchive
        var entries = arch.Entries.First(); // got an exception Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.

    }
    
    public static void Write(MemoryStream stream, StreamWriter writer, CsvWriter csv)
    {
        var columns = new List<string>
        {
            "Col1", "Col2", "Col3"
        };
        var values = new List<string>
        {
            "Val1", "Val2", "Val3"
        };
        
        foreach (var col in columns)
        {
            csv.WriteField(col);
        }

        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.Flush();
        writer.Flush();
        foreach (var val in values)
        {
            csv.WriteField(val);
        }

        csv.NextRecord();
        csv.Flush();
        writer.Flush();
        Bytes.AddRange(Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer().AsSpan(0, (int)stream.Length))));
        stream.Clear();
    }
}

public static class MemoryStreamExtensions
{
    public static void Clear(this MemoryStream source)
    {
        var buffer = source.GetBuffer();
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        source.Position = 0;
        source.SetLength(0);
    }
}
```